# Keep getting "null has 00null"

Tags: java, class

Im working with a stand-alone class, and a main driver, here's the stand-alone class:

```
public class Bugs{
   private String bugType;
   private int legs;
   private int arms;
   private String nativeTo;

   public Bugs(String bt, int l, int a, String nt){
      bt=bugType;
      l=legs;
      a=arms;
      nt=nativeTo;
   }

   public Bugs(String bt, int l, int a){
      bt=bugType;
      l=legs;
      a=arms;
      nativeTo="Not known";
   }

   public String getbt(){
      return bugType;
   }

   public void setbugType(String bugType){
      this.bugType=bugType;
   }

   public int getlegs(){
      return legs;
   }

   public void setlegs(int legs){
      this.legs=legs;
   }

   public int getarms(){
      return arms;
   }

   public void setarms(int arms){
      this.arms=arms;
   }

   public String getnativeTo(){
      return nativeTo;
   }

   public void setnativeTo(String nativeTo){
      this.nativeTo=nativeTo;
   }

   public String toString(){
      return bugType + " has " + legs + arms + nativeTo;
   }
}
```

And here's the main driver:

```
public class myBugs{
   public static void main (String args[]){
      Bugs asiaBeetle = new Bugs("Asian Beetle", 2, 2, "Japan");
      Bugs spider = new Bugs("Spider", 1000, 0);
      Bugs americanBeetle = new Bugs("American Beetle", 2, 2, "USA");
      System.out.println(asiaBeetle);
   }
}
```

JGRASP keeps returning "null has 00null", every time I run the main driver. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your classnames should not be plural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your constructor to this offcourse do the same for the other as well

```
public Bugs(String bt, int l, int a, String nt){
      bugType=bt;
      legs=l;
      arms=a;
      nativeTo= nt;
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Swap your assignments in your constructors :

```
public Bugs(String bt, int l, int a, String nt){
      bugType = bt;
      legs = l;
      arms = a;
      nativeTo = nt;
}
```

You have to do the same for the other :

```
public Bugs(String bt, int l, int a){
    bugType = bt;
    legs = l;
    arms = a;
    nativeTo="Not known";
}
```